# Spring logout access denied

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, logout, access-denied

I'm using Spring Security, trying to set up basic login\logout functionality. Login works ok, I store users in MySQL DB, and I'm able to log in, but I have problem with logging out. On home page I made a logout link, looking like this, but when I click it I get 403 Access denied, and user doesn't get logged out:

```
<a href="<c:url value="j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a>
```

And here is my security-context.xml:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loggedout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createoffer" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreate" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offercreated" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offers" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/loggedout"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />

</security:http>
```

And /loggedout is mapped to basic .jsp page, just saying "You have logged out."

Also, when I click logout link when I'm not logged in, it takes me to the login page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set the log4j org.springframework.security category to debug and paste the log of the logout request.

Comment: I'm begginer in this, how can I do that? 
Also, when I click logout link when I'm not logged in, it takes me to the login page, if that means anything to you.

Comment: Can you enable your logging settings, something like Log4J and enable debug mode logging for org.springframework.security. I can provide you the log4j.xml file if you want, you have to paste it in resources.

Comment: I've tried now, but it's just too confusing, i'm really bad at this config stuff, knowing where to put what... May I send you my whole project and if you can see it yourself, it's really small, I just started working on it..

Comment: Which version of Spring Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the 
        logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"

to the 
        security:logout
 and it is working as it should now.. But I thought it would work even without this parameter if I use /j_spring_security_logout as logout link.

Comment: I did this. Still not working for me
I have 
<security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_logout" access="permitAll" />
in the security config too

Comment: i got it working finally without the changes mentioned in my previous comment. Will add it as an answer to thisthread

Answer (score 1):

Add this as the first rule in the `<security:http use-expressions="true">` section:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_logout" access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: Now it gives me 404, and in console i read:
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/offers/j_spring_security_logout] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'

Comment: I would really help diagnose the problem if you enabled logging for your app. Are you using log4j, logback...?

Comment: I have a slf4j in my Maven Dependencies, but I haven't done anything with it. How should I set it up to give you log?

Answer (score 0):

Add this under the `<security:http use-expressions="true">` section:

`<security:csrf disabled="true"/>`

Worked for me.